# Finding the critical dimensions of an irregular shape

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a small issue in dealing with calculating critical dimensions(width and height) of an irregular shape. 
Given the input image :[image]

Consider the situation where the shape of a BLOB is like curved inward and hence to measure its width the traditional method of minBounding Rectangle doesn't work for the best.

[image]

I have tried the method of bounding with rectangle and using the tl,tr,bl,br(top left , top right , bottom left , bottom right) points from the box and using them as parameters for mid point calculation. and then drawing the lines through them. But this fails for an image curved inward.

Below is my traditional implementation of finding width and height using Boundingbox:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours 
import imutils 
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Measuring critical dimensions through midpoint(centroid)')
parser.add_argument('--image', help='Path to image file.')

args = parser.parse_args()
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

def midpoint(pta,ptb):
    return((pta[0]+ptb[0])*0.5,(pta[1]+ptb[1])*0.5)

im_in = cv2.imread(args.image, 0)
_, thres2=cv2.threshold(im_in, 170, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dilate = cv2.dilate(thres2,None)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate,None)

im_3=erode.copy()
blur=cv2.medianBlur(im_3,5)

_,contour2,_=cv2.findContours(blur,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for c in contour2:
    area=cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area >1000 and area <30000:
        print(area)
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.array(box,dtype="int")
        (tl,tr,br,bl)=box
        (tltrX,tltrY)=midpoint(tl,tr)
        (blbrX,blbrY)=midpoint(bl,br)
        (tlblX,tlblY)=midpoint(tl,bl)
        (trbrX,trbrY)=midpoint(tr,br)
        dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))

        dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))
        dA = round(dA,3)
        dB = round(dB,3)
        cv2.circle(blur,(int(tltrX),int(tltrY)),5,(255,255,255),1)
        cv2.putText(blur, "({},{})".format(dA,dB), (int(tltrX - 50),int(tltrY - 10) - 0),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 1)
        cv2.circle(blur,(int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        cv2.circle(blur,(int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        cv2.circle(blur,(int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        cv2.line(blur,(int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),(255,255,255),2)
        cv2.line(blur,(int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),(255,255,255),2)


        print(dA)
        print(dB)
        cv2.imshow('4',blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect the output to be something like from the mid point , i find the pixels at the boundary of the image(and the line is clipped of at the image boundary and i can get pixel values of those points) on the same line as that of the midpoint.(Without using the bounding box method)
[image]

Comment: Could you add an example output image?

Comment: Hi , unfortunately i dont have an exact resulting image , but the image i have attached above , is nearly close to the output , apart from the CENTRAL contour , where the line crosses the boundary (because of the boundingbox).

Comment: Could you include the expected sizes?  Maybe draw a few arrows on the picture? It is hard to imagine what you need to measure in that image.

Comment: Hey , Sorry if you were having trouble imagining , i have added the last image for reference, does it makes sense now ?

Comment: try 2 x the maximum of distanceTransform in each row and use the minimum

Comment: Thanks for you response, if u dont mind could you elaborate a little more

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to measure the holes in that shape. I missed that detail somehow! :) So instead of the convex hull, you want to measure the *convex skull*. The convex skull is a rather obscure problem, and there are no good solutions (best is O(n^7) or so I think). However, you could simplify that by finding the largest fitting rectangle, which is a simpler problem. Also, if you can make the assumption that the shape is aligned with the image axes, the problem becomes rather trivial. Though I'm not sure that that is the best way of measuring? Maybe an *average* width and height are best?